# How to handle empty object in if statement as false?

Tags: javascript

I ran across this case today

```
if ({}) {
  // This is returned as empty object is true
}
```

therefore need to figure out a way where `{}` is false, tried calling `.length` on an object I pass to the if statement, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you want to find out if an object has no properties, use `Object.keys`.

Comment: You sort of have to define what "empty object" means. That is has no `own` keys...?

Comment: Object.keys(obj).length > 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to achieve this.

From Mozilla's Documentation:

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a `for-in loop` enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

```js
if (Object.keys({}).length) {
  console.log('Object is not Empty');
} else {
  console.log('Object is Empty');
}

console.log(Object.keys({}).length);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use:

```
Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
```

Comment: You need to check for `Symbol`s too